# Signing Applescript Application So It Doesn't Ask For Password

Tags: macos, security, passwords, applescript, vpn

I have an applescript application I wrote modifies my network settings to connect me to my vpn provider. Problem: It asks me for my password every time I want to run it.
Hopeful Solution: It runs without asking for a password.

```
(************************   Run   *************************)
on run #{VPNconfiguration}
    set rand_vpn to random_vpn()
    set VPNconfiguration to pick_vpn(rand_vpn) # Returns a list with one item
    set VPNconfiguration to item 1 of VPNconfiguration # Selects that item from the list
    connect_vpn(VPNconfiguration)
end run

(********************   Random Vpn   **********************)
on random_vpn()
    set rand_vpn to some item of {"US-Cali", "US-West", "US-East", "US-Midwest", ¬
        "US-Texas", "US-Flordia", "US-Seattle", "US-Siliconvallay", "US-NewYorkCity"}
    return rand_vpn
end random_vpn

(*********************   Pick Vpn   ***********************)
on pick_vpn(rand_vpn)
    set VPNconfiguration to choose from list {¬
        "US-Cali", "US-West", "US-East", "US-Midwest", "US-Texas", "US-Flordia", ¬
        "US-Seattle", "US-Siliconvallay", "US-NewYorkCity", "Mexico", "Brazil", ¬
        "Canada", "Canada-Toronto", "UK-London", "UK-Southampton", "German", ¬
        "France", "Switzerland", "Netherlands", "Sweden", "Romania", "Hong-Cong", ¬
        "Isreal", "Russia", "Turkey", "Singapore", "Australia", "Australia-Melbourne", "Japan"} ¬
        with title ¬
        "VPN Connection Client" with prompt ¬
        "Choose One Location" OK button name ¬
        "This VPN" cancel button name ¬
        "Quit" default items {rand_vpn}
    if result = false then quit
    return VPNconfiguration
end pick_vpn

(********************   Connect Vpn   *********************)
on connect_vpn(VPNconfiguration)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell network preferences
            tell current location
                set aPPPoEService to a reference to configuration VPNconfiguration of service "AllVPNs"
                connect aPPPoEService
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end connect_vpn

(***********************   Quit   *************************)
on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: A signature is not going to help you. Changing network settings is a privileged task, so it's always going to ask for a password, unless the script  runs as root.

Comment: That depends on when you want it to run. If you're happy for the script to run once when a user logs on, you can setup a [LaunchAgent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: I want to be able to run it at anytime. I do start it on boot, but the connection drops sometimes and I need to reconnect. I have it as an app on my start bar. I want to be able to click it and have it run without asking for a password.

Comment: If the script can detect when the connection drops and automatically do the reconnection, then setting up as a LaunchAgent is all you would need to do, as you can state that you want it to run as root.